# How to use a loop to simply repetitive PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following variables that needs to be processed the exact same way. 
How can I simplify this code using a loop?

```
$var1 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var1']));
$var2 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var2']));
$var3 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var3']));
$var4 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var4']));
$var5 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var5']));
$var6 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var6']));
$var7 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var7']));
$var8 = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['var8']));
```

Thank-you!

Comment: foreach $_POST ??

Comment: Not tested but array map should help you to do it in a single line, `$result = array_map('trim',array_map('stripslashes', $_POST));` and them make that array to individual variables

Comment: I disagree with the target duplicate, the question isn't just about looping through `$_POST` values, it's about processing them and creating the exact same output (variable variables) but with a loop.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Why disagree? Seems someone disagreed with your answer. That "someone" I can safely say, was not me. Btw, you basically put the same answer as the dupe.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I said why I disagree. It's about the processing part, not the loop. The difference in the answer is a pretty big one, mine actually creates the same variables as the OPs question, the answer in the dupe doesn't create _any_ variables. It basically doesn't do OPs process at all. I'm not saying the question shouldn't be closed btw, I'm saying the target dupe only answers half the question, and it's not even the important half.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It does. That vote to reopen is yours right? Well I am not reopening. The dupe far as I'm concerned, stands.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, you do you, as always. OP said the variables "needs to be processed the exact same way", while the dupe only answers how to loop through an array. The question here is more asking about how to create the variables during the loop, not doing the loop itself. I don't know why someone would mark my answer as "not useful" when it does exactly what the OP needs, while the duplicate target doesn't explain half of OPs problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can loop through all of the `$_POST` values and create a new variable using curly brackets (`{` and `}`).

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = Trim(stripslashes($value));
}
```

The variable creation in this answer uses [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

**WARNING**: This basically does the same thing as the `extract()` function, which is considered insecure. I recommend you consider finding a new method to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's not the more elegant solution, I would say. A little bit of [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) salted by the use of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to accommodate with the `Trim(stripslashes())` looks better to me.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Yeah, but I always try to avoid `extract`, especially considering this is untrusted data (but to be fair, this basically does the same thing)

Comment: If untrusted data was the concern of the OP then stripslashes is a bad candidate also. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: `extract` does the same as what you are doing with variable variables. Both are extremely insecure.

Comment: @Dharman I'm aware of that, and I mentioned it in my second comment above. Just updated my answer to include that information.